# Is there a way to disable Treesitter in Telescope?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, plugin-treesitter, plugin-telescope

I have max file size rule for files, setup in treesitter config, it works:

```
require 'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
 highlight = {
  enable = true,
  is_supported = function()
    if vim.fn.strwidth(vim.fn.getline('.')) > 300 or vim.fn.getfsize(vim.fn.expand('%')) > 1024 * 1024 
    then
      return false
    else
      return true
  end
 }
}
```

but this setup doesn't work in telescope preview buffer anyway...

I tried this to disable highlight for telescope, but it doesn't work:
`vim.cmd([[ autocmd User TelescopePreviewerLoaded TSBufDisable highlight ]])`

Is there a way to disable Treesiter in Telescope (ideally for big files only)?

UPD 1. Added this to my `.config/nvim/after/plugin/telescope.lua`

```
vim.cmd([[
  autocmd User TelescopePreviewerLoaded set filetype=
]])
vim.cmd([[
  autocmd User TelescopeFindPre set filetype=
]])
```

and no help .. syntax highlinght in file preview works anyway

UPD 2: What interesting, if disable treesitter at all like this:

```
require 'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
 highlight = {
    enable = false,
 }
}
```

it successfully disables treesitter in telescope file preview too, but i lose (of course) syntax highlighting in simply opened files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution, this helped: `:h telescope.defaults.preview`.:

```
require('telescope').setup {
  defaults = {
    preview = {
      treesitter = false
    }
  },
}
```

it disables treesitter in telescope, but unfortunatelly at all..  According to this doc there is a way to disable treesitter by `filetype`, like  `preview = { treesitter = { disable = fileTypesTable }}`
but not by file size anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use the User event `TelescopePreviewerLoaded` to set options on the preview buffer

You disable highlighting you could do:

```
autocmd User TelescopePreviewerLoaded set filetype=
```

If you want to only disable highlighting for large file you can replace `set filetype=` by a custom call or command.

Comment: tried to add 
```
vim.cmd([[
  autocmd User TelescopePreviewerLoaded set filetype=
]])

vim.cmd([[
  autocmd User TelescopeFindPre set filetype=
]])
```
to my telescope config file, no results. Anyway big file preview is loading 2 minutes

Comment: Do you still have colorization or not anymore?

Comment: Yea, its still colorized

Comment: I don't have them colorized but for some they are still colorized the first time I visit them in the list. I suspect that the event is called after the file is first displayed.